# Variation of Triangle Inequality

Tags: inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Assume that for some $a\geq 0$, $b \geq b_0 > 0$ and $c \geq c_0 >0$ we have the following:
$$a^2+b^2 \leq c^2$$ 
Can I conclude that 
$$a \leq c - \alpha b$$ 
for some $\alpha > 0$? If yes, what is $\alpha$? Note that both $b$ and $c$ are lower bounded by some known positive constant.

I know it does not hold in general for $\alpha \geq 1$ and it obliviously holds for $\alpha = 0$, but I wonder if it hold for some other positive $\alpha$ perhaps as a function of $b_0$ and $c_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such an estimate does not exist. For $b_0 > 0$, $c_0 > 0$
and $x > 0$ choose
$$
b = b_0 \,, \, c = c_0 + x \,, \,  a = \sqrt{c^2 - b^2} \, .
$$
Then $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and
$$
 \frac{c-a}{b} =  \frac{b}{c+a} \le \frac{b}{c} = \frac{b_0}{c_0 + x}
$$
and that becomes arbitrarily small for $x \to \infty$.